# Cannot build my package due to ros/Joy.h not being found

Tags: ros, cmake, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like a pretty simple error to get past, but `catkin_make` cannot seem to find ros/Joy.h.

```
/home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/fly_from_joy.cpp:4:21: fatal error: ros/Joy.h: No such file or directory. compilation terminated.
```

I have already included `joy` into my `CMakeLists.txt`. Not sure what else to do:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ardrone_autonomy
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  joy
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254810/cannot-build-my-package-due-to-ros/joy.h-not-being-found/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-17**:
Seems to be a pretty easy error to look over, does no one know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer to be quite simple actually. Basically `#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>` instead of `#include<ros/Joy.h>` within your `.cpp` files.

---

Originally posted by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) with karma: 83 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0